# XCode highlighting random lines and calling errors when there isn't any

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I had to force shut down my computer, and XCode was open. I opened it back up, and now XCode is highlighting random things and calling them errors. For example, the line:

```
[[self managedObjectContext] save:nil];
```

is given the error:

> Bad receiver type 'int *'

I tried a clean then build, but the errors still remain. Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: restart you mac again and restart xcode again

Comment: restart won't work...

Answer (score 6):

You can delete the Derived Data from you organizer. This will let Xcode reindex your project. And hopefully fix your problem.

[Apple doc - About projects organizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-projects_organizer/articles/about_projects_organizer.html)