# Xcode throws random errors when there are none

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

Every *once in a while*, usually after I've done some **trial and error** on my code, Xcode **throws random errors at me** even though I've removed the previous incorrect code snippets, and even though I've restored my files to a stage where it last worked perfectly. In other words, **there are no errors** for sure, **yet my app crashes and Xcode generates errors**. I shall also add that when my iPhone isn't connected to my computer, the app runs just fine.

After having **removed everything that did cause errors** in the past, Xcode - as described above - instead points to random stuff as being incorrect such as closing brackets, viewDidLoad, **as if saying:**
*"Hey, I know there was an error before, can't find it now though but I know it's there somewhere so lets crash and point at something completely random such as a closing bracket"*.

I assume the **old project files are being cached** (or similar) somewhere but I can't for the life of me figure out where or how to get rid of them. I'm using **Xcode 4.5.2**, **iPhone 5 iOS 6.0.2**, **OSX 10.8.2** fwiw.

### What I've tried so far:

1. Clean, build, run, clean, rebuild, re-run. **[no change]**
2. Restart X-code, remove icon from home screen, step 1 again **[no change]**
3. Restart computer **[no change]**
4. Restart iPhone and simulator and reset simulator to factory settings **[no change]**
5. Delete the Derived Data from organizer as shown [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-projects_organizer/articles/about_projects_organizer.html), and suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664937/xcode-highlighting-random-lines-and-calling-errors-when-there-isnt-any) **[no change]**
6. All above including restoring my entire iPhone **[Works]**
7. Create a new project and rebuild the nib file and copy past code from old project to new **[Works]**

Yes, **alternative 6 and 7 do work** but I can't spend hours on restoring my iPhone to factory settings or recreate my entire Xcode project every time this happens. Alas, it does happen quite often these days.

Any other **ideas or suggestions?**

Comment: Try deleting the contents of ~/Library/Caches.  Do you have time machine?  Try rolling back to the last save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Deleting the conents of Caches did not solve it either and unfortunately, I'm not using time machine. Any other suggestions?

Comment: At a last ditch effort, one time I had to delete the contents of ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState.  This worked for me on a similar error once.  Otherwise I would try removing Xcode and reinstalling it.

Comment: I don't have a folder named Saved Application in my library, not in any other folder either :/ Couldn't find the com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState file either. Reinstalling Xcode would probably work too but I would rather not go through all that trouble, don't want to lose all my settings etc. But I guess that's what I'll have to do if nothing else works. Cheers

Comment: Have your tried: Option + Shift + Command + K for cleaning and removing build folder?

Comment: That did it! Excellent. Write that as an answer and I'll gladly mark it as the right one. Can't believe that work when rebooting computer, iPhone, simulator, etc didn't.

Comment: No answer so I I'll just post it myself then for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to gmogames for pointing out the following solution which did the job for me.

In **Xcode** press:

```
Option + Shift + Command + K
```